# File Download Dialog Box in IE6 'Action Canceled message

Tags: configuration, download, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have created site which is having PDF download option. When I click on a link to download a file with IE6 installed, initially a browser window appears with the File Download Dialog box in front (asking to Open, Save, Cancel). Regardless of which option I choose, the browser window stays open and returns an 'Action Canceled - Internet Explorer was unable to link to the web page you requested. The page might be temporarily unavailable.'

Though the browser window stays open, whatever option I choose is handled accordingly. For example, if I click 'Open', the file downloads and then I am left with the aforementioned browser window. If I hit 'Cancel' the File Download dialog box closes but the browser window stays open.

The behavior does not happen at all with IE7. I've made sure the computer has all of the available updates. I'm just wondering if this behavior is normal for IE6 or if I have some setting that I am missing. Can you please assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is browser and version specific. You can control the behavior via the [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537641#sniffing):

> This behavior occurs if the content type that is specified in the header that is returned from the server does not match the file name that is specified in the `Content-Disposition` header.

**References**

- [Handling MIME Types in Windows Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775148)